# HP DL360 Gen6 Fan failure with new fans

Tags: hp-proliant

The server reported 2 fans failed so I bought a whole new set and replaced the two that were failed. The server then immediately reported all fans failed so I tried replacing the other two and then re-installing the old ones to no avail. I have checked and can hear all fans running at full speed.

Some other posts suggest disabling the onboard fan check however I do not get a bios prompt. Is there a way out for me or am I looking at replacing the motherboard?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using original replacement parts (fans)? If not, are you sure your new fans are 100% compatible to the old fans? Do you have damaged the motherboard? If not, I see no reason to replace the motherboard. PS next time always replace all fans at the same time with original replcement fans.

Comment: moreover there is a second error regarding the psu and on bsnk 6, cpu2. either you killed something or open a support case on hp to get your warranty rights. but i believe that your not having a nbds for this device. I think that the system has not enough power at all for the Complete system. remember that it is set to use both power supplies

Comment: Unplug all PSUs, change the CMOS battery to a new one, perform a full CMOS reset as described in the manual and see if it changes anything. G6/G7 are known to report bizarre error combinations when CMOS battery is discharged.

Comment: djdomi - I unplugged that power supply during troubleshooting, it had nothing to do with the errors.
Peter Zhabin - A good suggestion, I will buy a new battery and give it a try.